# Mass changes with speed, so shouldn't that mean reactionless drives are possible?

Tags: speed-of-light, acceleration

Increasing the angular momentum of an object will increase the mass of an object. The thought experiment I have in mind is 2 identical discs, `left` and `right`:

- spin `left`
- push `right` off of `left`
- stop `left` spinning
- spin `right`
- pull `left` back towards `right`
- stop `right` spinning
- start over

I imagine it inch-worming along as each disc has its mass momentarily increased to act on the other.

So why is this type of system *theoretically* impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a sense in which mass does increase with speed. However, to increase something's speed, you have to put energy into it. That energy also has mass, it also figures into center-of-mass calculations, and it's exactly equal to the mass gained by the object when it speeds up. So no scheme of this sort can work.

Comment: so the energy it takes to spin a disc fast enough to double its mass has a mass; and that mass is exactly equal to the mass of the disc. thank you, that makes sense

Comment: FYI: Einstein Never Approved of Relativistic Mass and today the concept has been largely abandoned (except for by students and laymen ;-)). Instead the concept of '*relativistic momentum*' is used. See https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.3204111